# Flex: conditional embedding of images

Tags: apache-flex, image

We are working on a flex project where we want to balance two challenges
a) want to ensure that there is minimal need to be connected to internet- so it can be used offline. This will be used in rural locations with flaky connections

b) Reduce file size by only embedding those assets in compile mode as is required

Broadly, the project will go down one of three flows in the module called, based on user choice- Path A,  Path B and Path C, which will require image set-A, set-B & set-C respectively (based on settings in the module)

We want to send over all images in Set-A or set-B or set-C right upfront in the module called, based on choice made in primary project, to minimize need for connectivity once accessed. At the same time I want to avoid sending all three sets and bloating up download size three times.

The question is how do I conditionally embed images such that if I am going down path A, the module sent down only has images of set-A

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling Flex on Fly/Runtime from primary project on server?

If NO, its mean you are compiling it in IDE, in that case i suggest build 3 Application 
For Path-A B nd C, you dont need to rewrite whole application again just ReWrite **Application.mxml** for three apps and emebed rrelative assests in them

IF YES, same ans seprate app.mxml for each path

EDIT: Anotther option is [conditional compilation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_09.html#138195) *It is To include or exclude blocks of code for certain builds, you can use conditional compilation*

hopes that helps

Comment: We are compiling in the IDE. We want to avoid creating three module.mxml's- as the business logic is very similar and only image sets changing. Maintenance will be a problem. Hence want to check if we can embed conditionally

Comment: I mean to say, just seprate Assets in Application.mxml i.e. move VIEWS, BUSINESS-LOGIC and other DATA from main APPLICATION.MXML to sub components although you are using APPLICATION1-2-3.MXML as Container of ALL these things and Embeding Assets1-2-3 respectively.CALL sub components, views, data other than images in them and its remains same for ALL APPLICATION1-2-3.MXML and any change you made in sub componet automatically reflects in all 3 apps, its easy one i think, you may find some better solution, Good luck

Comment: Plz ck for conditional compilation, i think you are looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

We had to solve a similar problem with asset localization, and we ended up creating external RSLs to link in "asset packages". However, this does require a bit more attention to the build process, since you have to pay closer attention to linkage and dependencies across RSLs. Most of these problems go away if all of your libraries are linked as external as apposed to merged-in-code (not just for your app, but any local libraries you may use as well). This is not necessarily required, but it does help ensure everything you need gets linked in.